# how to plot the function in the following

Tags: plotting, implicit

$$\Phi=e^{-\xi}*\cos\eta-\xi$$
$$x=\cosh\xi*\cos\eta$$
$$y=\sinh\xi*\sin\eta$$
how to plot streamline $\nabla\Phi$ in x-y coordinate.

Comment: You have not used Mathematica syntax. Does this question concern the software application Mathematica or the Wolfram Language? If not, you are on the wrong site. If it does, enter your functions using the proper syntax and show what you have tried.

Comment: is it `Cos[eta-xi]` or `Cos[eta]-xi` ?

Answer (score 4):

Since $\Phi$ is in terms of $\xi,\eta$ and not in terms of $x,y$ we first have to express $\xi,\eta$ in $x,y$ before taking the gradient

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
eq1 = x == Cosh[xi]*Cos[eta]
eq2 = y == Sinh[xi]*Sin[eta]
{xiSol, etaSol} = {xi, eta} /. First@Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {xi, eta}];
```

This gives solutions that depends on $c_1,c_2$ in integers. So I set these to 1 otherwise will not be able to plot. Any integer value will work.

```
xiSol = xiSol /. C[1] -> 1;
etaSol = etaSol /. C[2] -> 1;
```

Now you are able to evaluate $\Phi$ as function of $x,y$ and plot

```
phi = Exp[-xiSol]*Cos[etaSol] - xiSol ;
gradPhi = Grad[phi, {x, y}];
```

But the gradient have complex values. Because solutions $\eta,\xi$ are complex. So you have to plot either the real, im or abs. Here is the abs value of Grad of $\Phi$

```
VectorPlot[Evaluate@Abs@gradPhi, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

May be you also want `ContourPlot`?

```
ContourPlot[Abs@gradPhi, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is for different range

```
ContourPlot[Abs@gradPhi, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]